# Git merge command

Tags: git

I'm reading the following article: http://github.com/guides/keeping-a-git-fork-in-sync-with-the-forked-repo, where they mention essentially pulling in changes from two repos at the same time by creating the following alias:

```
pu = !"git fetch origin -v; git fetch wycats -v; git merge wycats/master"
```

This makes sense, but, as someone new to Git, I'm curious why the commands is that versus:

```
pu = !"git fetch origin -v; git merge origin/master; git fetch wycats -v; git merge wycats/master"
```

or something along those lines.  Basically, I'm wondering why the argument to merge is wycats/master and how it knows about origin/master automatically.  Looking for a quick explanation.

Comment: Most likely the original article is wrong. `git merge` does not automatically know to look for `origin/master`. As far as I can tell it should be as you suggest, or the last command in the original should be `git merge origin/master wycats/master` to do an octopus merge of both branches into the current branch.

Comment: It's also here: http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/developer, which is where I originally saw it. Does

    git merge origin/master wycats/master

also work?  Haven't tried that.

Answer (score 2):

I am at a loss as to why an octopus merge would take place here (msysgit1.6.5 in a DOS session).
An octopus is for one merge with several parents.

If I follow the routine of "two modifications in to remote repo to pull back", here is what I see before the final merge (after one round of pulling):

[image]

`chgB` (from main, that is "origin") and `chgA` (from remote "`mainA`") have been merge one by one in `master`.

Two other changes has been made and fetched: `chgB2` from origin and `chgA2` from `mainA`.

If I try to only merge `mainA/master`, I ends up with:

[image]

`chgA2` has been merged. `chgB2` from "main" (origin) is still hanging out there...

But if I try one more change in `mainA`, and specify both remote repos in the merge command, then an octopus merge takes place:

```
C:\Prog\Git\tests\octo\dest1>git merge origin/master mainA/master
Trying simple merge with 9e3e16d8e75cec3be621c47fb72e955cc2574f0f
Trying simple merge with 4dfb282a31d5bafddb244c84b66ede41e28f1042
Merge made by octopus.
 a.txt |    2 +-
 b.txt |    3 +--
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
```

[image]